# Nginx Reverse proxy excluding files

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I've a landing page done using wordpress and is hosted on example.com. I've an app running on app.example.com on external url. When user try to access wordpress files, it should be served from example.com and if that url or folder is not available the url must be masked and must go to remote url as example.com/$1. I've tried using nginx reverse-proxy but it is not working.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string @proxy;
}

location @proxy {
    proxy_pass https://example.com/$1;
    proxy_set_header HOST $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: If the files are not found it must go to proxy. currently it is going to 404 of wordpress. For example if I've searched example.com/test then the files need to be served from external domain google.com but url must be shown as example.com/test.

Answer (score 0):

The `try_files` only checks if actual files exist on filesystem. Once it founds a file that exists, it uses that one to serve a response. `try_files` does not act on any HTTP status codes.

Since you always have `/index.php` in your filesystem, the `@proxy` target is never used.

You need to implement the functionality by hooking into WordPress 404 error generation hook and perform the proxying there.

Comment: Thank you. Since I'm not well versed with Wordpress, I'm trying the luck with nginx. 
``location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
}

location @proxy {
    proxy_pass https://app.example.com/$1;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    recursive_error_pages on;
    error_page 404 = @wordpress;
}
location @wordpress {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?$query_string break;
}``

Comment: Please don't add configuration snippets to comments, they cannot be read properly.